# Identify these vintage Ford hubcaps

Tags: ford, part-identification

I am hoping to find an enthusiast who knows a bit about classic Fords.

Can anyone identify these vintage Ford hubcaps ?

[image]

Comment: What is the diameter of these? The bottom seems a little wider, but both are about the same. I just cannot get an exact size to help match them. The top pattern appears to be common to the 1930's, if that helps, but the one which appears to match it is about 5.75" ... it appears this one is bigger than that.

Comment: @Paulster2: I'm afraid I couldn't say: I found this image out of context!

Comment: @Paulster2: what about the finish? It looks painted to me. Could they be replicas? 
Is there a museum I could contact?

Comment: Well, here are the two which I believe they are for ... looks about as close as you are going to get: [top hub cap](http://www.macsautoparts.com/ford_mercury_early/hub-cap-v8-embossed-painted-ford-blue-stainless-steel-5-3-4-ford-passenger-2.html) and [bottom hub cap](http://www.macsautoparts.com/ford_mercury_early/hub-cap-ford-embossed-painted-ford-blue-stainless-steel-5-3-4-4-cylinder-model-b-ford-passenger-1.html) if that helps.

Comment: Yes, they look as though they have been painted over. I would bet Henry would have had a fit had these come off the assembly line liking like that ;-)

Comment: @Paulster2 That comment should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here are the two which I believe they are for ... looks about as close as you are going to get: [top hubcap](http://www.macsautoparts.com/ford_mercury_early/hub-cap-v8-embossed-painted-ford-blue-stainless-steel-5-3-4-ford-passenger-2.html) and [bottom hubcap](http://www.macsautoparts.com/ford_mercury_early/hub-cap-ford-embossed-painted-ford-blue-stainless-steel-5-3-4-4-cylinder-model-b-ford-passenger-1.html) if that helps.

Yes, they look as though they have been painted over. I would bet Henry would have had a fit had these come off the assembly line looking like that ;-)